# QWebEngineView freezes while autoscrolling a web page

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, loops, qtwebengine

I'm using C++ with Qt v5.9.1.

I'm dealing with a problem when I use QWebEngineView. It freezes in the AutoScrolling, then it unfreezes and returns to normal after the AutoScrolling finish.

---

### **Freezes:**

```
void MainWindow::on_BTN_Load_clicked()
{
    QUrl url = QUrl(ui->lineEdit->text());
    webview->page()->load(url);
    connect(webview->page(), &QWebEnginePage::loadFinished, this, &MainWindow::on_PageLoadFinished);
}

void MainWindow::on_PageLoadFinished()
{
    disconnect(webview->page(), &QWebEnginePage::loadFinished, this, &MainWindow::on_PageLoadFinished);
    
    //Get the page's height
    webview->page()->runJavaScript("document.body.scrollHeight",[&](const QVariant &result) {set_PageHeight(result.toInt());});
}

void MainWindow::set_PageHeight(int TheHeight)
{
    ThePageHeight = TheHeight;
    ScrollDownPage();
}

void MainWindow::ScrollDownPage()
{
    TheCurrentVerticalScroll = 0;

    while (TheCurrentVerticalScroll <= ThePageHeight)
    {
        webview->page()->runJavaScript(QString("window.scrollTo(0, %1);").arg(TheCurrentVerticalScroll));
        TheCurrentVerticalScroll += 100;
        
        QEventLoop loop;
        QTimer t;
        t.connect(&t, &QTimer::timeout, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
        t.start(30);
        loop.exec();
        qApp->processEvents();
    }
}
```

---

### **Works:**

But, this problem doesn't appear when I click manually on a button that call the same **AutoScrolling** function.

```
    void MainWindow::on_BTN_Load_clicked()
    {
        QUrl url = QUrl(ui->lineEdit->text());
        webview->page()->load(url);
        connect(webview->page(), &QWebEnginePage::loadFinished, this, &MainWindow::on_PageLoadFinished);
    }
    
    void MainWindow::on_PageLoadFinished()
    {
        disconnect(webview->page(), &QWebEnginePage::loadFinished, this, &MainWindow::on_PageLoadFinished);
        
        //Get the page's height
        webview->page()->runJavaScript("document.body.scrollHeight",[&](const QVariant &result) {set_PageHeight(result.toInt());});
    }
    
    void MainWindow::set_PageHeight(int TheHeight)
    {
        ThePageHeight = TheHeight;
        // ScrollDownPage();     //I disable this now
    }
    
    void MainWindow::ScrollDownPage()
    {
        TheCurrentVerticalScroll = 0;
    
        while (TheCurrentVerticalScroll <= ThePageHeight)
        {
            webview->page()->runJavaScript(QString("window.scrollTo(0, %1);").arg(TheCurrentVerticalScroll));
            TheCurrentVerticalScroll += 100;
            
            QEventLoop loop;
            QTimer t;
            t.connect(&t, &QTimer::timeout, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
            t.start(30);
            loop.exec();
            qApp->processEvents();
        }
    }
    
   //I add this:
    void MainWindow::on_BTN_Scroll_clicked()
    {
        ScrollDownPage();
    }
```

---

### **What I want:**

I want to scroll the web page automatically, not manually by clicking the button.

Thanks.

Comment: I have tested with the code that says it does not work and I have not had problems, I have tested it in Linux with Qt 5.9.1, maybe the error is elsewhere, you could share the complete code to test it.

Comment: @eyllanesc These is the complete code. I used it too under linux mint 18.2. Perhaps you tried to load a small page, so the AutoScroll attains the end of the page quickly before you observe the problem (Freeze).

Comment: @eyllanesc These is a big page for example: 
[link](http://www.instructables.com/id/Flickering-Solar-Garden-Light)

Comment: I tried it with the link and I had no problems.

Comment: @eyllanesc Can you recheck what happend directly after calling this function: ScrollDownPage();

Comment: see this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B97wfiRYrzYjNnJVOEItcl9CT00/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @eyllanesc These my code: [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0ByYSO6K4jXdgZmQxd3pXVG90dVU?usp=sharing)

Comment: see this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B97wfiRYrzYjUHhwbkk5eTBUS28/view?usp=sharing